# How to change diffForHUmans default message

Tags: php, laravel

How can i custom the default `diffForHumans` output message

Example: `7 hours after`
I want to change it to : `7 hours more`

this is my code:

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($quiz->waktumulai)->diffForHumans(\Carbon\Carbon::now("Asia/Jakarta")->toTimeString())}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use, this

```
$comment->created_at->diffForHumans(null, true)
```

to remove the `ago,from now, etc` then you can append the ago by yourself . So you'll end up with:

```
$comment->created_at->diffForHumans(null, true).' more'
```

> (NB: you may need to check why this does not work by default)

> Ref: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Answer (score 1):

One way is to replace string from result

```
$result= Carbon::now()->addDays(3)->diffForHumans( Carbon::now());

Str::replace('after', 'more', $result)
```